# Sources for contract sysadmin work

Tags: untagged

Does anyone have some good recommendations for sources of contract sysadmin work (other than personal contacts, who you can rest assured I'm already harrassing ;-))  I'm based in the California Bay Area, but am open to other regions.

Comment: If you have a specific question you could always ask in here.  Check out the local LUGs.  Check out to see if SAGE, LOPSA, or any other sysadmin group has any local user groups, and ask them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it depends on what area your expertise lies in, but I believe with MS consulting if you become a certified partner, MS will forward professional services requests to you based on area of expertise within MS or geographic location. It's then up to you to close the deal with the prospective client.